# GraphQL - optional after value

Tags: graphql

I have the following GraphQL query:

```
query workflowState($id: String!, $after: String!){
    workflowState(id: $id) {
    issues(after: $after) {
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage,
        endCursor
      }
      nodes {
        id
        title
        labels{
          nodes {
            id,
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The first time I run the query I do not want to pass `after` to the `issues` I would like to get all issues from the beginning.

When I parse the response, if `hasNextPage` is true I would like to call the query again and this time pass `endCursor` to `after` so I get the next set of paginated results.

I can successfully parse the response and make the second call but
how do I go about making the first call that does not have and `after` value?

I have tried passing an empty or non-existent UUID, and I get the error: `Invalid input: after must be an UUID`

Comment: Doh! that was way to easy... I had mistaken the `String!` for a non required var, whereas the `!` means required

Comment: @xadm Write an answer and ill accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definition

> query workflowState($id: String!, $after: String!){

... makes `after` variable required.

### Solution:

Just remove '!' - exclamation mark:

> query workflowState($id: String!, $after: String){

... and [when not required] don't pass 'after' variable - `issues(after: $after)` will get (will be evaluated to) undefined value. This way 'after' will work as an optional parameter.